# How does aggregate affect geom_text?

Tags: r, ggplot2, aggregate

I found this code below online somewhere and have been trying to adjust it to what I need. While doing this I found several situations, which give an error message, but I just do not understand why.

I tried the following code with 4 different versions of calculating the mean:

```
library(ggplot2)

mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)

means1 <- aggregate(mtcars[1], mtcars[2], mean)
means2 <- aggregate(list(mpg = mtcars$mpg), list(cyl = mtcars$cyl), mean)
means3 <- aggregate(mtcars[1], list(mtcars$cyl), mean)
means4 <- aggregate(mtcars$mpg, mtcars[2], mean)

means <- means1  #or means2, means3, means4
means[2] <- round(means[2], digits=2)

p <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = mpg))+
     geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center")
p + stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_sdl", fun.args = list(mult = 1), 
             geom = "errorbar", width = 0.2, color = "red") +
stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point", color = "red") +
geom_text(data = means, aes(label = means[2]),hjust = -0.5)
```

It works fine with means 1 and means2. But means3 gives the error message:

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'cyl' not found.

And means4 gives the error message:

> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (3): label, x, y

However if I omit the geom_text line then both means3 and means4 produce a plot without any error.

I want to understand how the change in the calculation of the means affects the last line. It is probably really simple, but I just can’t figure it out. What exactly causes these errors and why is there no error if I omit geom_text?

I compared the dataframes before deciding to post here. And these were my (obviously wrong) conclusions:

`geom_text(means, aes(label = mpg) )` works with means1 and means2. Since the column 2 is still named mpg in means3 it should work, but it doesn’t. Why not?

`geom_text(data = means, aes(label = mpg) )` does not work with means4, since there is no column mpg anymore. So I changed it to
`geom_text(data = means, aes(label = means[2])` which should work independently from the column name.
There is a column cyl, so it does not show the same error as mean3. But why does it complain about the length? All four means show the length to be 2.

Comment: One way to investigate this on your own would be to print each of `means1`, `means2`, etc on the console and see how `means3` is different. Do you see a difference? Now can you connect that to the language in the error message?

Comment: A useful command to explore things like this is str(). Compare the output of str(means1), str(means3) and str(means4). In this case, can be done even easier with just looking at output dataframes. You will see that in means3 you don't have column named cyl any longer.

Comment: @ joran & kintany: I did look at the data before posting and added my train of thought to the question, as it was too long for a comment.